# how to convert .net web services into WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Is there tool/way to conver webservices into WCF services? like .net frame work application 1.1 to 2.0 provided by MS visual studio.

any help would be appritiated.

Thanks,
Pradeep